# Grant access to module in Yii2

Tags: php, yii

This is possible to set permission with RBAC methods (Role, Permission) to access a module in Yii2?
I want to allow users with spacial Role to access for one of my module.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can even limit accesses in module's `init` method or use filters.

Comment: @AliMasudianPour that is bad practice if module is part of an package installed via composer, for example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use Filter for this purpose:

```
'modules' => [
    'roles' => [
        'class' => 'aj\admin\Module',
        'as access' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['Administrator'],
                ]
            ]
        ],
]
```

Comment: What does the 'as access' represents? Is it framework convention or what? Where can I find the doc for 'as <something>'?

Comment: @Araz Jafaripur I get error `"app\modules\wind_panel\models\User" refers to a app\modules\wind_panel\models\User component. yii\web\User is expected.`

Answer (score 1):

You can set behaviors in a module just as you can in controllers.

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\admin;

use yii\filters\AccessControl;

class Admin extends \yii\base\Module
{
  public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\admin\controllers';
  public $defaultRoute = 'overview';

  public function behaviors()
  {
    return [
      'access' => [
      'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
          [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['basic.superadmin', 'basic.admin'],
          ]
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

  public function init()
  {
    parent::init();

    $this->layout = 'main';
  }
}
```